# in Meteor.template.rendered how to make a call after everything is rendered (after the {{#each}} loop finishes)

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Hi I have this template

```
<template name="users">
   {{#each user}}
    <li id="{{_id}}"> 
        <input type="checkbox" checked /> 
        <span><select name="colorpicker">
                {{#each color}}
                  <option value="{{mColorCode}}" {{selected ../mColor mColorCode}}>{{mColorName}}</option>
                {{/each}}
              </select>
        </span>
        <img width="40"  src="data:image/png;base64,{{mImage}}" />  
        <span class="name">{{mUsername}}</span>
        <p><span class="description">{{mDescription}}</span></p>  
    </li>  
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

What i want to do is after the template is rendered, i want to convert the dropdown to a colorpicker. I'm using a jquery plugin

```
Template.users.rendered = function(){
      $('select[name="colorpicker"]').simplecolorpicker({picker: true});
}
```

The problem is sometimes its not working, (Sometimes the call is being made before the dom being ready.)

I want to call this plugin after everything is rendered. and not for each user added, how can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I used, it's also a hack if someone has a better solution please post it.

What i did was i put the rendered template in the callback of the subscribe of my collection.

So my code was something like this :

```
Meteor.subscribe('trackedUser',function(){
  Template.users.rendered = function(){
  ......
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found Meteor to be a little funny with how often it renders templates, and jQuery functions can end up building up.

I've taken to adding `console.log("users rendered");` to understand how many times and when the render callback is triggered.

One thing I've had some success with is wrapping that template inside another, and then tying the callback to the outside template.  Something like this:

```
<template name="container">
    {{> users}}
</template>
<template name="users">
   {{#each user}}
    <li id="{{_id}}"> 
        <input type="checkbox" checked /> 
        <span><select name="colorpicker">
                {{#each color}}
                  <option value="{{mColorCode}}" {{selected ../mColor mColorCode}}>{{mColorName}}</option>
                {{/each}}
              </select>
        </span>
        <img width="40"  src="data:image/png;base64,{{mImage}}" />  
        <span class="name">{{mUsername}}</span>
        <p><span class="description">{{mDescription}}</span></p>  
    </li>  
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

And this just add the callback to the container

```
Template.container.rendered = function(){
      $('select[name="colorpicker"]').simplecolorpicker({picker: true});
      console.log("rendered");
}
```

Not totally sure why it works, but it has for me, hopefully someone can illuminate us both.

Comment: It's a smart solution, and it's logical since naturally a template is rendered when all his children are rendered, but it didn't work with me, no idea why.

Comment: Hmmm. Did the console log? Can you see a pattern to when it works and when it doesn't - e.g. it works the first time but not after that...?

Comment: It seems random, because in each template i'm using a collection, so it seems to me that sometimes the parent template finishes rendering, but another record is fetched, and the child template is rendered again

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a pretty old post, but since I had a problem and I think I've found a better way, here it is. The containing template will technically be *rendered* even while the contents are rendering. In my case I was trying to initialize a materialize modal. To make it work It had to do the following.

template.html

```
<div class="row" id="eventResults">
  {{#each eventResults}}
    {{> eventResult}}
  {{/each}}
</div>

<template name="eventResult">    
  <div class="modal event" id="{{id}}">
    <div class="modal-content">
    ...
```

and template.js

```
Template.eventResult.onRendered(function(){
  this.$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
```

By calling the code on the onRendered of the child element **and** using `this.$('...')`, the code doesn't get called multiple times for each element, just once each.